# multipart shape horizontal split

Tags: tikz

How come the horizontal split seems not to work whereas the vertical one does ?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,standalone]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.multipart}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[my shape/.style={rectangle split horizontal , rectangle split parts=#1, draw}]
  \node [my shape=2] 
  {a  \nodepart{two} b };
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[my shape/.style={ rectangle split , rectangle split parts=#1, draw}]
  \node [my shape=2] 
  {a \nodepart{two} b };
 \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `rectangle split` in your horizontal node:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.multipart}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[my shape/.style={
  rectangle split, 
  rectangle split horizontal , 
  rectangle split parts=#1, 
  draw
  }]
  \node [my shape=2] 
  {a  \nodepart{two} b };
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[my shape/.style={ rectangle split , rectangle split parts=#1, draw}]
  \node [my shape=2] 
  {a \nodepart{two} b };
 \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn. That's a lot of `rectangle split`